# making scripts for div work independant of each other after adding wrap div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, so please excuse my code if it's not good. I can't figure out how to make the script work after I add the `wrap1` div.

Without the `wrap` div it's almost working, but the content starts extending in the `title` div. I used a `wrap` to separate them, and the code stops working. The script would still use the `.learn` right?

I have tried a few things but to no avail, this is what I tried:

```js
$(".learn").click(function() {

  $learn = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $learn.next();
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $learn.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Learn less!" : "Learn More!";
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->

</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->

</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Here is the wraps removed so you can see what im talking about. This does what I want but as you can see the styling looks horrible....

```js
$(".learn").click(function() {

  $learn = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $learn.next();
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $learn.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Learn less!" : "Learn More!";
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">This is a title</div>
  <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  <div class="content">
    This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">This is a title</div>
  <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  <div class="content">
    This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">This is a title</div>
  <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  <div class="content">
    This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">This is a title</div>
  <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  <div class="content">
    This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">This is a title</div>
  <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  <div class="content">
    This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

With the wraps, the content is not the next element after `.learn`. You have to go up one level to the container, go to the next container, and then down to the `.content`

```js
$(".learn").click(function() {

  $learn = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $learn.closest(".wrap1").next().find(".content");
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $learn.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
      return $content.is(":visible") ? "Learn less!" : "Learn More!";
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.container div {}

.wrap1 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap2 {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.container .learn {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
}

.container .content {
  display: table;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->

</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->

</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->

  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap1">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>
    <div class="learn">Learn More!</div>
  </div>
  <!--makes the content expand below this div-->
  <div class="wrap2">
    <div class="content">
      This is just some random content. This is just some random content. This is just some random content.<br>This is just some random content
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--holds the content below the wrap one div-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```